# Exist a Subclass

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning

I was trying to solve the below Exercise

If $B\in\sigma(A) $,  then there exists a countable subclass  $A_B$ of  $A$ such that $B\in\sigma(A_B)  $

Hint: Use good set principle to create a class with the desired property

Please explain try to explain every step of the solution